# Component Lifecycle in Svelte - When to read DOM properties

Tags: svelte-3

In Svelte how do I batch reads of properties that trigger relayout. In React you do measurements in useLayoutEffect. Things like intersectionObserver and resizeObserver are pretty noisy so I do not want to read when they fire. I want to read these properties batched to run once before all DOM mutations take place each render. I want to make sure reads and writes do not get interleaved (this causes DOM thrashing).

```
//bad DOM reads and writes are interleaved causes multiple re-layouts
el.className = "one"
a = el.clientWidth  // triggers relayout
el2.className = "two"
b = el.scrollWidth  // triggers relayout

//good DOM reads and writes are batched single re-layout
el.className = "one"
el2.className = "two"
a = el.clientWidth  // triggers relayout
b = el.scrollWidth
```

I don't really understand what order things happen in Svelte's render.

If I have a page with many components are all beforeUpdate functions run before any DOM mutations take place?

Is beforeUpdate the best time to measure the DOM?

Is the render synchronous (i.e. all pending changes flushed to the DOM at once)?

(I understand I can bind to clientWidth, other properties like scrollWidth are not available)

This is my attempt is there a better way?

https://svelte.dev/repl/fb561a1aca45460489ecf2eb69a1948e?version=3.22.3